# Wall plugin not working even though it is in the /thewall/, the right directory

Tags: javascript, mootools, javascript-framework

I'm trying to use this mootools plugin but it doesn't work at all

This plugin is from this URL I downloaded the plugin and tried to apply it, the folder called `/thewall/` is in the right directory, I have no idea why it's not working

[Here](http://mootools.net/forge/p/the_wall) is the URL of the plugin.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>The Wall</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="demos/mootools-1.3.1/mootools-core-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="demos/mootools-1.3.1/mootools-more-1.3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="source/wall.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Define The Wall
    var maxLength    = 100; // Max Number images
    var counterFluid = 1;
    var wallFluid = new Wall("wall", {
                    "draggable":true,
                    "inertia":true,
                    "width":150,
                    "height":150,
                    "rangex":[-100,100],
                    "rangey":[-100,100],
                    callOnUpdate: function(items){
                        items.each(function(e, i){
                            var a = new Element("img[src=/thewall/"+counterFluid+".jpg]");
                                a.inject(e.node).fade("hide").fade("in");
                            counterFluid++;
                            // Reset counter
                            if( counterFluid > maxLength ) counterFluid = 1;
                        })
                    }
                });
    // Init Fluid Wall
    wallFluid.initWall();

    </script>



    <style>
    /* Minimal Css Required */
    #viewport{
        width:900px;
        height:450px;
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:0 auto;
        background:#212121;
    }

    #wall{
        z-index:1;
    }
    </style>   
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="viewport">
        <div id="wall">
        </div>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: dunno, i find the plugin works just fine with little mod - here's the video wall i built with it: http://www.webtogs.co.uk/thewall/ - make sure you have the right images or mod the callback to do something else.

Comment: your current setup implies you have 100 sequentially named jpg images in /thewall/ folder.